# C++ build setup to ignore changes in comments

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, comments

Is it possible to setup the build chain in a way such that any changes in comments (or whitespace) are ignored? For example whenever a comment in a header file is changed, every source file that includes it is re-compiled, even when that's completely unnecessary.

When the preprocessor is done with removing comments from the modified file, the build chain could first check if the output actually changed. If not, it should act as if the file itself didn't change.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 btw.

Edit: @MikeSeymour, VS's cl.exe has a switch /Gm for minimal rebuilds. It's not well documented, but I think it kinda does what I'm asking for. **But** it's incompatible with the /MP switch for using multiple cores. On my dual core (w/ hyperthreading), /Gm would need to skip the compilation of ~3 out of 4 units on average. While I find it doubtful that this is the case, I'm not even sure how to evaluate whether /Gm is worth it or not.

Comment: Interesting. You'd basically want an extended build system which processes a target, then compares the result with the existing file, and does *not* overwrite if they're the same. Then you'd combine that with separating the preprocessing stage into a separate target, and you'd be done. Would be a nice feature!

Comment: I've a vague idea that Visual Studio does that anyway - I think I remember it producing messages like "ignoring irrelavent changes". I could be wrong though. For other build platforms, you can do exactly what you want with [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: ccache _does not_ prevent recompilation for whitespace changes outside comments (and rightly so, IMO)

Comment: Xoreax Incredibuild may support the feature(s) you describe. It _does_ come with a builtin preprocessor, anyway

Comment: This would be difficult because the build system needs to compare a *before* and *after* copy of the file, but only *after* is available.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But caching an intermediate header without comments should be trivial

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You have to have a build system that will let you trigger build events if some predicate is true.   What you'd like is a predicate that says, "this file has changed in an semantically interesting way".

A good approximation of such a predicate exists, in the form of our [SmartDifferencers](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) family of tools that compare source code files, using deep knowledge (e.g, a production parser) of the structure of the source code.  In particular, the SmartDifferencer will show changes in source code in terms of changes to language constructs (e.g., identifiers, statements, declarations, blocks) and plausible editing actions (insert, replace, delete, move, rename, rename-across block, etc.).  It isn't interested in layout or comments (unless you force it to be).  So it is pretty easy to get the SmartDifferencer to tell if a source code file has changed something other than comments or whitespace.  SmartDifferencers exist for a wide variety of languages.

Now, how do you get the build system to cooperate?  Unix Make triggers on a predicate, but not this kind; what it actually does is trigger build events on entities based on recency of file dates compared to the target.  You can fake this by having a dependency on a "changed_signal" file, by manufacturing such a file, if the SmartDifferencer sees an interesting difference.

Comment: Nice, that's even more than what I was asking for. It might even be too much. Imagine "only" inserting an empty line: How is the debugger supposed to know that every breakpoint following that line is off by one?

Is it possible to integrate this SmartDifferencer with VS 2010?

Comment: Well, in the case of the debugger, its pretty easy.  It has a mapping of breakpoints to line numbers in the initial file.  You insert arbitrary lines; the IDE builds a table that says "N lines inserted at legacy line M".  Now any legacy breakpoint line number can be mapped to the a modern line number.   Whether the IDE can keep track of this table over long periods is another matter, but I've been pretty impressed with MS Visual Studio to do just this during my debugging sessions pretty well.  Don't remember how well it works across invocations of the IDE.

Comment: Regarding "does SmartDifferencer integrated into VSStudio"... well, I don't know the answer, we haven't gotten around to that step. It is a tool that can be invoked from the command line, and returns error status codes. I believe VSStudio will let you run any such tool. Whether you can insert that into the build process the way you described... I've never looked at how MSVisual Studio actually manages the build steps these days.  Under the assumption it is something like make files (didn't MS use to push something called NMake?) it seems like it ought to be possible.

Comment: I once wrote an Eiffel language like compiler that even went further and a significant change was a change in a function code or a change in the memory layout of structures.  So even adding members at the end of a struct would not case recompilations. It was fast as hell and it compiled Eiffel->C++. That we keep separate compilation unit was nice in 1980s but it for sure is a serious root problem of slowness now in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

No.

How can the compiler know that the only changes you made to a file were in the comments, until it *compiles* that file?

Subsequent files must then be recompiled because the dependent file did change, even if the resulting binary was the same.

Comment: The OP is saying that changing a comment in a .hpp file could result in hundreds of .cpp files being re-compiled with no relevant changes in the header. Yes the .hpp needs to be re-examined to see if there's a change, but when no relevant change was detected, you can save all those .cpps from being re-compiled. The only time this would not be possible is when you do crazy rare things like ending a .hpp with `/*` and then putting `*/` in the including file. (not sure you can even do that!)

Comment: It's possible to ignore changes to comments by just preprocessing and not compiling; that's what [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) does. I've a vague idea that Visual Studio does something similar (I think it sometimes prints messages along the lines of "ignoring irrelevant changes"), but it's a long time since I've used that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of techniques to avoid lots of inter-dependencies. Try using forward declaration.

With using forward declaration you only need to compile the code that actually uses the code. Scott Myers book can tell you more. Has a good few pages on this subject.

Comment: Maybe better suited as a comment, since it doesn't answer the question in any way.

Comment: Christian - I was assuming that (s)he was implying that changing one file requires a whole bunch of other files to be compiled.

Comment: Maybe, but the actual question is of a completely different nature, anyway. Surely forward declarations are a good idea, but just not an answer to his question.

Comment: Thank you Ed. You're right, tools like forward declarations and the Pimpl idiom are very useful. But - at least on paper - changing the tool chain sounds a lot easier than changing the code and/or mindset of our developers. :)